# ACM Certificate with count=0 & aws_acm_certificate_validation fails due to for_each

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have code like below

```
//Create acm certificate for livy_cert
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "livy_cert" {
  count = local.count
  domain_name       = "${var.subsystem}-${var.component}-livy.${var.region_fqdn}"
  validation_method = "DNS"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

//Validation route53
resource "aws_route53_record" "certificate_validation" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.livy_cert[0].domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }
  name    = each.value.name
  records = [each.value.record]
  ttl     = 60
  type    = each.value.type
  zone_id = module.core_info.route53_zone_id
}

//Validate certificate before assigning
resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "livy_alb_validation_cert" {
  count                   = local.count
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.livy_cert[0].arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.certificate_validation : record.fqdn]
}
```

As you can see my cert is with count variable, however terraform plan fails when my count =0 as

> for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.livy_cert[0].domain_validation_options

fails to parse due to 0 index is not valid. I also tried with

> for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.livy_cert.*.domain_validation_options

However, that also fails when count =1

Any Idea of how it can be fixed?

Comment: Did you try explicitly add `depends_on` to `aws_acm_certificate_validation`?

Comment: @rkm there is a default dependency gets added when you mention one resource in another

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [flatten](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/flatten.html#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each) the list of `domain_validation_options` before iterating over it:

```
// Create acm certificate for livy_cert
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "livy_cert" {
  count = local.count
  domain_name       = "${var.subsystem}-${var.component}-livy.${var.region_fqdn}"
  validation_method = "DNS"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

// Validation route53
resource "aws_route53_record" "certificate_validation" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in flatten([
      for cert in aws_acm_certificate.livy_cert: cert.domain_validation_options
    ]): dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  name    = each.value.name
  records = [each.value.record]
  ttl     = 60
  type    = each.value.type
  zone_id = module.core_info.route53_zone_id
}

// Validate certificate before assigning
resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "livy_alb_validation_cert" {
  count                   = local.count
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.livy_cert[count.index].arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.certificate_validation : record.fqdn]
}
```

(Note, for `livy_alb_validation_cert`, I have used `livy_cert[count.index]` rather than `livy_cert[0]`, just for tidiness)

Comment: can you give me an example with the count? I have tried example without providing the count in the resource that works but as soon as I add count in aws_acm_certificate, aws_route53_record logic fails

Comment: This suggestion should only work if you have  `count` in your `aws_acm_certificate` resource - the loop shouldn't work at all if you don't have a `count` so I'm not sure what's happening there. I'll update the code to be clear what I mean though

Comment: @Ixop I just tried out that & it fails with `Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.` when count is 1

Comment: I don't understand where you're getting that error. Can you please show the whole command and response? That error message is coming from AWS, not Terraform.

Comment: It has worked, one of my lookup failed as my teammate changed setting for testing